# Find Duplicates in array of transactions objects using JavaScript, and combined duplicates in array of array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, javascript-objects

I have a array of transactions objects, where i need to find duplicates based on property(A object is duplicate if it's all values are same except ID and TIME, time difference should be within 1 mins).
I need to combined identical duplicates transactions as a Array objects.

Below are the input of transactions.

> I tried using Reduce functions but couldn't get the expected output.

```
var newArray = transactions.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
      //finding Index in the array where the NamaCategory matched
      var findIfduplicateExist = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
        let accepoch = new Date(item.time).valueOf();
        let currepoch= new Date(curr.time).valueof();
        if(item.sourceAccount === curr.sourceAccount &&
        item.targetAccount===curr.targetAccount &&
        item.amount===curr.amount&&
        accepoch<currepoch+(1*60*1000))
          let obj={
           'id':curr.id,
            'sourceAccount':curr.sourceAccount,
            'targetAccount':curr.targetAccount,
            'time':curr.time,
            'category':curr.category,
            'amount':curr.amount 
          }
      })
      // if in the new array no such object exist, create a new object 
      if (findIfNameExist === -1) {
        acc.push(obj)
      } else {
        // if attributes matches , then push the value 
        acc[findIfNameExist].value.push(curr)
      }
  return acc;

}, []);
```

Input transactions:

```
[
  {
    id: 3,
    sourceAccount: 'A',
    targetAccount: 'B',
    amount: 100,
    category: 'eating_out',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    sourceAccount: 'A',
    targetAccount: 'B',
    amount: 100,
    category: 'eating_out',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    sourceAccount: 'A',
    targetAccount: 'C',
    amount: 250,
    category: 'other',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    sourceAccount: 'A',
    targetAccount: 'B',
    amount: 100,
    category: 'eating_out',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    sourceAccount: 'A',
    targetAccount: 'B',
    amount: 100,
    category: 'eating_out',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    sourceAccount: 'A',
    targetAccount: 'C',
    amount: 250,
    category: 'other',
    time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'
  }
];
```

The Expected output is as below:

```
[   
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "B",
      amount: 100,
      category: "eating_out",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "B",
      amount: 100,
      category: "eating_out",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "B",
      amount: 100,
      category: "eating_out",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"
    }  
  ], 
  [
    {
      id: 5,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "C",
      amount: 250,
      category: "other",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "C",
      amount: 250,
      category: "other",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"
    }   
  ] 
]
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, even if it did not get you all the way there.

Comment: Which JS-Version do you need to support?

Comment: @HerrErker it's Node 8.1.3

Comment: @misorude updated my question with code i tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier (and more efficient) when you first get a copy of the transactions that is sorted by id. I assume that the id is an incremental number, so that later transactions always have a greater number. That way you only have to compare the timestamp with the last one in the accumulator:

```js
// Example data
const transactions = [ { id: 3, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z' }, { id: 1, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' }, { id: 6, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'C', amount: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z' }, { id: 4, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z' }, { id: 2, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z' }, { id: 5, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'C', amount: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' } ];

const newArray = [...transactions].sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id).reduce( (acc, curr) => {
    let group = acc[acc.length-1], 
        prev = group && group[group.length-1];
    if (!prev || prev.sourceAccount !== curr.sourceAccount ||
                 prev.targetAccount !== curr.targetAccount ||
                 prev.amount !== curr.amount ||
                 Date.parse(prev.time) + (1*60*1000) < Date.parse(curr.time)) {
        // different keys or larger time difference: create new group
        acc.push(group = []);
    }
    group.push(curr);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: It looks charms to me, just need your input on the assumption you made, what if we sort by time,isn't that will be a better solution.

Comment: Sure, if we cannot assume id are incremental, then `.sort((a,b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time))` should do the trick.

Comment: Just be careful though, as it seems to me that timestamps could in theory be equal, depending on how much detail the millisecond part has, but still then.... The id would then be better as it is guaranteed to *not* be equal ever.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in concise way via one [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = [{ id: 3, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z' }, { id: 1, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' }, { id: 6, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'C', amount: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z' }, { id: 4, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z' }, { id: 2, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'B', amount: 100, category: 'eating_out', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z' }, { id: 5, sourceAccount: 'A', targetAccount: 'C', amount: 250, category: 'other', time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z' }] 

const sort = arr => arr.sort((a,b) =>`${a.id}${a.time}`.localeCompare(`${b.id}${b.time}`))
const getTime = obj => new Date(obj.time).getTime()
const isDub = (arr, obj) => arr.length ? Math.abs(getTime(arr[arr.length-1]) - getTime(obj))/1000 > 60 : false

const result = Object.values(sort(data).reduce((r, c) => {
  let key = [c.sourceAccount, c.targetAccount].join('-')
  r[key] = isDub(r[key] || [], c) ? r[key] : [...r[key] || [], c]
  return r
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

You do need to pre-sort the array so that you only deal with the last entry when comparing for duplicate based on your within minute requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do multi-column sort and then find duplicates in each group.

```
const SECONDS = 60;
const MILLISECONDS = 1000;

const getTimeDifference = (t1, t2) => {
  return new Date(t1) - new Date(t2);
};

const multiLevelSort = (transactions = [], colsToSort = []) => {
  return transactions.sort((a, b) => {
    return colsToSort.reduce((acc, col) => {
      if (acc !== 0 || a[col] == b[col]) {
        return acc;
      }

      const c1 = a[col], c2 = b[col];
      if (col === "time") {
        return getTimeDifference(c1, c2) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
      } else {
        return c1 > c2 ? 1 : -1;
      }
    }, 0);
  });
};

const isUniqueTransaction = (prev, curr, matchKeys = []) => {
  if (!prev || !curr) {
    return true;
  }
  return matchKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    /* Current key is time then difference should be more than equal
     * 1 min for transaction to be unique.
     */
    if (key === "time") {
      return (
        acc ||
        getTimeDifference(curr[key], prev[key]) >= 1 * SECONDS * MILLISECONDS
      );
    }

    return acc || prev[key] !== curr[key];
  }, false);
};

function findDuplicateTransactions(transactions = []) {
  const matchingKeys = [
    "sourceAccount",
    "targetAccount",
    "amount",
    "category",
    "time"
  ];
  const sortedTransactions = multiLevelSort(transactions, matchingKeys);
  let duplicates = [];
  let group = [];
  sortedTransactions.forEach((curr, idx, transactions) => {
    // Previous Transaction find check if current trasaction is unique.
    const prev = group && group[group.length - 1];
    const isUnique = isUniqueTransaction(prev, curr, matchingKeys);
    if (isUnique) {
      if (group.length > 1) {
        duplicates.push(group);
      }
      group = [];
    }
    group.push(curr);
  });

  // Push last group if it has more than 1 transaction
  if (group.length > 1) {
    duplicates.push(group);
  }

  // Sort duplicate trasaction groups based on first transaction in group
  return duplicates.sort((a, b) => {
    return getTimeDifference(a[0].time, b[0].time);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.sort` and `Array.forEach` like below to achieve this

I have initially sorted array by concatenating property values (excluding `id` and `time`) and in increasing timestamp

```js
let arr = [{  id: 3,  sourceAccount: 'A',  targetAccount: 'B',  amount: 100,  category: 'eating_out',  time: '2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z'},{  id: 1,  sourceAccount: 'A',  targetAccount: 'B',  amount: 100,  category: 'eating_out',  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'},{  id: 6,  sourceAccount: 'A',  targetAccount: 'C',  amount: 250,  category: 'other',  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z'},{  id: 4,  sourceAccount: 'A',  targetAccount: 'B',  amount: 100,  category: 'eating_out',  time: '2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z'},{  id: 2,  sourceAccount: 'A',  targetAccount: 'B',  amount: 100,  category: 'eating_out',  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z'},{  id: 5,  sourceAccount: 'A',  targetAccount: 'C',  amount: 250,  category: 'other',  time: '2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z'}];

let res = []
 ,  getKey = ({id, time, ...rest}) => Object.entries(rest).map(([k, v]) => k + '-' + v).join(';')
 ,  getTimeDiff = (t1, t2) => Math.abs(new Date(t1).getTime() - new Date(t2).getTime())

arr.sort((a,b) => {
    let akey = getKey(a)
      , bkey = getKey(b)
  
    return akey.localeCompare(bkey) || +new Date(a.time) - +new Date(b.time)
  })
  .forEach((d, i, t) => 
    i == 0 || 
      (getKey(d) == getKey(t[i-1]) && getTimeDiff(t[i-1].time, d.time)/1000 < 60)
      ? res.push((res.pop() || []).concat(d))
      : res.push([d])
  )

console.log(res)
```